# Advantage of using method in OOP Javascript

Tags: javascript, oop, object

I came across a JS file which was built in a strange manner:

```
var modal = (function(){
  var method = {};

  // Center the modal in the viewport
  method.center = function () {};

  // Open the modal
  method.open = function (settings) {};

  // Close the modal
  method.close = function () {};

  return method;
}());
```

I understand the part of wrapping a function into the "modal" object, but why bind all the functions to `method` and then return it at the end?

Comment: Seems like the object should be called `methods`...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a design pattern to group functionalities into modules, and to get rid of global variables. This leads to better code.

1. The function call creates a 'closure' i.e. a scope for all the variables declared within that function, they stay even after the function has exited, and they are not visible outside the function.

   ```
          var modal = (function(){
          var method = {};
          // Center the modal in the viewport
          method.center = function () {};

         // Open the modal
         method.open = function (settings) {};

         // Close the modal
         method.close = function () {};

         return method;
       }());  // This function call here creates a "closure" ( scope )
   ```
2. Now to make certain members of the module available outside the module, they need to be returned from the function, here `return method` does exactly that, making `method` a public object of the module , which can be used outside.
3. Instead of creating invididual variables like `open`, `close` etc, the related functions are assigned as properties ( keys of the object ) to the main `method` object, so that returning the single object makes all the related functions accesible. This also serves the purpose of reducing the number of identifiers (names ) within the closure scope.

Read this very good article on this `modular` pattern :

http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2007/06/12/module-pattern/

Comment: I could be wrong, but I don't think this code actually creates a closure. I don't see any local variables being preserved by the function scope.

Comment: Yes, for the code provided,there aren't any. But about the pattern.

Comment: Ah, gotcha; I misunderstood.

Answer (score 3):

For that specific code, there is no advantage. It does the same as:

```
var modal = {

  // Center the modal in the viewport
  center: function () {},

  // Open the modal
  open: function (settings) {},

  // Close the modal
  close: function () {},

};
```

However, if you put a local variable in the function, that's a different matter:

```
var modal = (function(){

  // a variable that is private to the object
  var local = 'hello world';

  var method = {};

  // Center the modal in the viewport
  method.center = function () {};

  // Open the modal
  method.open = function (settings) {};

  // Close the modal
  method.close = function () {};

  return method;
}());
```

Now all the methods in the object can access the private variable, but it's not directly reachable from outside the object.